# ¿Cómo cerrar Pop-Up en HTML?

Tags: html, css, popup

Tengo una ventana modal que aparece automáticamente cuando la pagina se carga. El problema es que al pulsar el boton de "X" el Pop-up no se cierra. ¿Hay alguna forma de cerrarlo sin usar Javascript o Jquery? Aquí dejo el código del HTML

```
index.html 
<div class="modal-wrapper" id="popup">
<div class="popup-contenedor">
   <h2>Titulo de la Modal</h2>
   <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Dolor deleniti in porro, officia velit quaerat modi doloribus similique aspernatur impedit quod, laudantium reiciendis! Similique nihil eius esse, illum assumenda soluta!. </p>

   <a class="popup-cerrar" href="#popup">X</a> 


</div>
```

Comment: Por favor proporciona un [**ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable**](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), preferiblemente en un **fragmento de código** dentro de la misma pregunta. ¿Qué has tratado hasta ahorita?

Comment: Estás pidiendo que no se use JavaScript para cerrar el popup, pero ¿no estás usando JavaScript para abrirlo?

Answer (score 1):

Esta es una ventana modal hecha sin JavaScript, ni jQuery, sólo con CSS.

```css
.btn {
  position: relative;
  padding: 8px 16px;
  font-family: 'psychotik';
  font-size: 1.2em;
  font-weight: normal;
  color: #fff;
  text-shadow: none;
  border-radius: 16px;
  background: #00A6B6;
  box-shadow: inset 2px 2px 1px #007f8b;
}

.btn:hover {
  background: #FF9C00;
  box-shadow: inset 2px 2px 1px #995f02;
}

#modalContent {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  z-index: 6;
  margin: -2% 0px 0px -150px;
  float: left;
  width: 300px;
  color: #fff;
  line-height: 22px;
  padding: 15px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background: #00A6B6;
  border: 1px solid #fff;
  box-shadow: 0px 2px 1px #999;
}

#modal {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  z-index: 5;
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  display: none;
  opacity: 0;
}

#modal>a {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  z-index: 1;
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

:target {
  display: block!important;
  opacity: 1!important;
}

#modalContent>a {
  position: absolute;
  top: -4px;
  right: -4px;
  color: #00A6B6;
  border-radius: 2px;
  background: #fff;
  padding: 4px;
}
```

```html
<a href="#modal" title="" class="btn">Pincha aquí</a>
<!-- La modal -->
<div id="modal">
  <a href="#cerrar"></a>
  <div id="modalContent">
    <h1>Soy una ventana modal</h1>
    <p>Hecha sin JS ni jQuery, solo CSS3</p> <a href="#cerrar">X</a> </div>
</div>
```

Comment: estabas usando comillas tipográficas en vez de `""`, `‹` en vez de `<`, `/* */` para comentarios en el HTML en vez de `<!-- -->`... Por favor intentemos tener cuidado con el código que se presenta en las respuestas. No sé si esto es de un editor en particular, pero si es así, te diría que no lo uses al copiar el código para pegar acá. Además, para código que se puede ejecutar en tu respuesta, conviene usar el botón `< >` (y probarlo antes de publicarlo).

Comment: @Mariano gracias; no controlo mucho cómo puedes ver.

Answer (score 0):

Aquí hay una opcion bastante simple:

Código Javascript

```
onclick=”window.opener.location.reload(); window.close();”
```

Comment: Disculpa, y donde deberia poner ese codigo?

Comment: @SpaceSpace <a class="popup-cerrar" href="#popup"  onclick=”window.close();">X</a>

Comment: Creo que la pregunta dice "sin usar JavaScript o jQuery"

Answer (score 0):

Al href del ancla, dejándole solo # debería recargar la pagina original y por ende no mostrarte mas la ventana modal

Answer (score 0):

La verdad, solo replicaré un código «muy similar» que circula en la web «entre otros». No entraré en detalles, pues si desean mas información lo mas justo es que visiten el sitio que tome de referencia:

[Crear Ventana Modal con solo CSS](http://soyfrontend.com/crear-ventana-modal-con-solo-css/)

```css
#popup {
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
  position: fixed;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  right:0;
  bottom:0;
  margin:0;
  -webkit-animation:autopopup 2s;
  -moz-animation:autopopup 2s;
  animation:autopopup 2s;
}

@-webkit-keyframes autopopup {
  from {opacity: 0;margin-top:-200px;}
  to {opacity: 1;}
}
@-moz-keyframes autopopup {
  from {opacity: 0;margin-top:-200px;}
  to {opacity: 1;}
}
@keyframes autopopup {
  from {opacity: 0;margin-top:-200px;}
  to {opacity: 1;}
}

#popup:target {
  -webkit-transition:all 1s;
  -moz-transition:all 1s;
  transition:all 1s;
  opacity: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
}

.popup-contenedor {
  position: relative;
  margin:7% auto;
  padding:30px 50px;
  background-color: #fafafa;
  color:#333;
  border-radius: 3px;
  width:50%;
}

a.popup-cerrar {
  position: absolute;
  top:3px;
  right:3px;
  background-color: #333;
  padding:7px 10px;
  font-size: 20px;
  text-decoration: none;
  line-height: 1;
  color:#fff;
}
```

```html
<div class="modal-wrapper" id="popup">
  <div class="popup-contenedor">   
    <h2>Titulo de la Modal</h2>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Dolor deleniti in porro, officia velit quaerat modi doloribus similique aspernatur impedit quod, laudantium reiciendis! Similique nihil eius esse, illum assumenda soluta!. </p>   
    <a class="popup-cerrar" href="#popup">X</a>   
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Cuando publique esta solución, no me había percatado que la pregunta llevaba ya un buen tiempo publicada, quizás no debí revivirla puesto que para ser sinceros es una mala pregunta cuyo código no es verificable como lo menciona @Ricky al OP.